# Populating textboxes from a hashtable

Tags: c#, winforms, hashtable

I'm creating an agenda program using windows form application, I'm trying to load data from a file into a hash table and display this data into text boxes. The labels on the text boxes are dates but these dates are of the form (`dd MMMM dddd` e.g 30 November Friday) and are used as key values for the hash table. The dates in the file are of the form (`dd MM yyyy`). A sample of the data in the file is shown.

10/07/2012 Will go to swimming at 10.30 *

30/11/2012 Will go to swimming at 15.30 *

When I load the form, the data should be shown in the corresponding textbox. For example Will go to swimming at 15.30 * must be shown under text box with label "30 November Friday" (because it corresponds to date 30/11/2012). I was able to split the data into key value pairs as in the code below:

```
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("Path/ajand.txt");

   string line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      key = line.Substring(0, 10);//gets date
      value = line.Substring(10);//gets string
      hT.Add(key, value);
    }
```

How do I add the data to the corresponding textboxes?

Comment: Should the subject not rather be: Populating textboxes from a hashtable?

Comment: Are you dealing with only dates in 2012? I ask you because didn't mention  a year component for the date format in the text boxes.

Comment: @chamila_c the date format on the text boxes doesn't show the year, it's of the form (dd MMMM dddd) but dates in the file show the year as in dd MM yyyy

Comment: So do you have access to the underlying date (i.e. including the year component) that is used to populate the text box, or do you only have access to the text itself (that is in the format dd MMMM dddd)?

Comment: @chamila_c i only have access to the text itself i.e the text of the form dd MMMM dddd there is no underlying year component.

Comment: So how would you decide which textbox to assign to if you have entries in the data file as follows:

 - 10/07/2012 Will go to swimming at 10.30 *
 - 10/07/2013 Will go to swimming at 15.30 *

Or is that a non-issue because you're only ever dealing with dates spanning a single year (e.g. just 2012)?

Comment: no it's not for a single year. The the form updates the dates on labels. There are also buttons to navigate between weeks and a calendar as well. so if you have 10/07/2013 Will go to swimming at 15.30* it would be shown in the text box with the label 10 July Wednesday for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Convert.toDateTime (see msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx) for converting the date to your desire format.

Then, loop through each entry in the hashtable

```
foreach(var entry in hashTable)
{
    //todo: convert entry.key (which is the date) to your format
    //      then set the label to the formatted date.
    //      lastly, set the text for the textBox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to convert the data in both the form and the data file into DateTime instances and compare them. However, given that the dates in the form (in the labels) lack a year component, your best bet will be to convert the data from the data file into a DateTime object, and to then extract the string format for that date (in the same format as per the form data). At this point a string comparison will allow the dates to be matched up. E.g:

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry dataEntry in hT)
{
   //Will throw a FormatException if 'dataEntry.Key' doesn't represent a valid date format
   DateTime keyAsDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataEntry.Key);

   //This overload of 'ToString' uses CurrentCulture
   string comparisonKey = keyAsDate.ToString("dd MMMM dddd");

   if(formLabel.Text.Equals(comparisonKey, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
       formTextBox.Text = dataEntry.Value;
   }
}
```

Comment: i get an error on the line
    `DateTime keyAsDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataEntry.Key);`

saying "object does not contain a definition for key "
I don't understand why.

Comment: hmmm - maybe explicitly typing the hash table items would do the trick - see latest edit: `foreach(DictionaryEntry dataEntry in hT)`.

Comment: it still gives a similar error message "System.Collections.DictionaryEntry does not contain a definition for key"..

Comment: i restarted the program and the previous modification 
`foreach(DictionaryEntry dataEntry in hT)` did the trick. Thank you.:))))

Comment: oops the error is gone but the data isn't populated at all. TextBoxes are empty. It should work, don't know why it isn't working. Also tried stepping into the code but couldn't place the error..